# wrong sign with NeumannValue

Tags: differential-equations

I want to use `NDSolveValue` with Neumann boundary condition. The documentation says this https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html . In the details section they explain how `NeumannValue` works. Now I have two examples:

```
f = NDSolveValue[{-u''[x] - u[x] == -NeumannValue[-1.5, x == 3], 
DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 0]}, u, {x, 0, 3}];
f'[3]
f[0]
```

and

```
f = NDSolveValue[{-u''[x] - u[x] == -NeumannValue[-1.5, x == 0], 
DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 3]}, u, {x, 0, 3}];
f[3]
f'[0]
```

According to the documentation it should hold that `c=1` and `g=-1.5` and therefore `n.u=-1.5` for `x==0/3`. `n` should be the normal vector which is `+1` for `x==3` and `-1` for `x==0`.

What I do not understand is why the sign of `f'` is the same and positive in both examples given above. Is it due to my poor understanding or the documentation?